# How to pass bash task in Azure devops as filePath

Tags: bash, unix, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a linux script and run that in Azure devops as bash task .
My script is running fine when I add the code as inline Option but while trying to give the script as filePath ,the variables $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) and $(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias) variables inside the script is failing as Unable to get the variables .
[image]

How to pass the script as filePath and how to access the two variables if I pass the filepath and not as inline option.

Comment: I assume you are trying this on Release pipeline right? Are you sure you have there your script? Is this a part of artifact? Did you try to check what is inside the folder by running `ls $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`?

Comment: Also please double check what syntax you use in your file. You shold refer in file to variable via environment variables like `$VARIABLE_NAME` rather tahen `$(Variable.Name)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the script as inline value, the pipeline engine automatically replaces `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` with the correct value.

When you run a script file, the engine doesn't analyze or change it, so it wont replace the variables. But the variables are still available, as [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables). So `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` should become `$SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY`. This will work for inline script as well.